# Problem with data structure in a post for Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase, data-structures

I am trying to create a post for Firebase's database. The structure is a bit complex. The JSON format for the structure is this:

```
{
"wordList":[{"category":"Drink",
"category_id":"1",
"words":["Water","Tea"]},
{"category":"Food Item",
"category_id":"2",
"words":["Food","Burger"]}]
}
```

This is what I wrote in Swift:

```
    func addWords() {
    newRef = Database.database().reference().child("wordList")
        let word = wordTextField.text
    var addWordPost : [{String : AnyObject, Int : AnyObject, [String] : NSArray}]
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I am getting these errors:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to declare this `[String: [[String: Any]]]`, can not use `{}` in swift

Comment: Hi @a.masri I want the part between the {} to be a dictionary. What should I use?

Comment: use `[ ]` this is a dictionary read this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `{}` in `Swift` just use `[]` instead, you structure should can be

```
[String: [[String: Any]]]
```

And then start mapping from there, considering your structure would be like this in swift

```
[
    "wordList":
    [["category":"Drink",
    "category_id":"1",
    "words":["Water","Tea"]],
    ["category":"Food Item",
    "category_id":"2",
    "words":["Food","Burger"]]]
]
```

The First key is `WordList` and the value of it is `[[String: Any]]` .
The array contains dictionary `[String: Any]` so after getting the array then one index of that array that leaves you with the dictionary `[String: Any]`  now hold up one key of this dictionary also contains an array the key `words` holds an array of `[String]`.

Check out this [tool](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) paste you'r `JSON` and you will have an idea of how its created and how to map out values of it, also read about [Swift Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) would help you too.